# In a TYPO3 template, v:variable.set works... but f:variable doesn't

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers, typo3-9.x

## The problem

I have customized something in a file overriding this `news` extension file `Templates/Styles/Twb/Templates/News/List.html`. This was working...

```
<v:variable.set name="special.category" value="1" />

<f:if condition="{special.category}">
  <f:then>
    Do something for the special category when the variable's boolean value is 1
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    Otherwise do something else
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

But when I tried to change it to this, it no longer works...

```
<f:variable name="special.category" value="1" />

<f:if condition="{special.category}">
  <f:then>
    Do something for the special category when the variable's boolean value is 1
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    Otherwise do something else
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

## Some documentation

- https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79402-VariableViewHelperForFluid.html
- https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/SetViewHelper.html

## My platform

- I am using TYPO3 9.5.3 but would also like to know the answer for 8.7.

Comment: Which Typo3 version do you use?

Comment: I edited my question adding that I'm using TYPO 9.5.3.

Comment: I think its the dot in the variable name. Maybe vhs:variable is implemented different in this case. Maybe <f:variable name="special" value="{category: 1}"/> this works?

Comment: Oh that makes sense... <f:variable name="special" value="{category: 1}"/> does work. Thank you!

Comment: I post this soluation as answer, so u can close this question right? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its the dot in the variable name. Maybe vhs:variable is implemented different in this case. Maybe `<f:variable name="special" value="{category: 1}"/>` this works?